# Non-Adverbial "as is"

Tags: prepositions, conjunctions

I know the common adverbial usage of "as is" as in,
*Leave it as is.*

As a non-native English speaker I found a strange-to-me but common English usage of non-adverbial "as is" and sometimes also "as are/was/were", which I cannot find its listing in the dictionary and in my (basic) English grammar book. With my search in the Corpus of Contemporary American English, I was able to find 4 kinds of of non-adverbial "as is".

**1. as is = like**

*Ride quality and straight-line speed are also impressive, as is the Pro 4's resistance to tread cuts.*

*Certainly, looks are a factor, as is overall vibe.*

*As is the case in many academic libraries, space is at a premium.*

**2. as is = as it is**

*As far as is possible, populations must want to move and must have active influence.*

*As much as is possible, we must leave our sorrows.*

**3. as is = as**

*We experienced attrition from year 1 to year 2, as is expected in multiyear studies.*

**4. as is = as well as being**

*As is well-known, Hawthorne himself was considered a very handsome, indeed, a beautiful.*

My question, simply put, "What is this?".

Comment: I am no grammar expert to help you analyse the role of the words in each of these contexts, but I am, I believe, a literate native speaker, and you have correctly identified various uses for this phrase. "as" is a complex word in English which performs a variety of odd, fossilised roles in set phrases and other constructions. My small desktop dictionary dedicates a whole page to "as" and its constructions, a good reference dictionary will dedicate many pages to it. Someone will come up with chapter and verse as an answer, but go forth in confidence!

Comment: Don't think of this as an idiomatic expression. It's just the word _as_ being used with the verb _is_. _as_ has many different uses.

Answer (score 1):

I think "as is" is often used as shorthand for: "as it currently is" or "the way things are now", though I cannot tell you the grammatical rules of why this came into being. This is how it is used in your defining example.

Comment: But is it a formal usage?